# Help with basic structuremap wiring

Tags: c#, structuremap

```
var container = new Container(x =>
                                              {
                                                  x.For<IEngine>().Use<V6Engine>();
                                                  x.For<ICar>().Use<HondaCar>();
                                              }
);

ICar car = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICar>();

Console.WriteLine(car.Noise());
```

I am getting the error:

```
StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily ClassLibrary1.ICar, ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

I read the quickstart, and I understood that if you wireup a particular interface that is also used in a constructor, you don't have to explicitly wireup the interface in each classes constructure.

So in the above, I wired up IEngine to V6Engine, and then ICar to HondaCar (that has a constructor that has an IEngine that I have already wired up).

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
container.GetInstance<ICar>();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes that works, but why?  in a web application objectfactory would work?  container won't be in scope in other places other than the file that contains the container configuration code.

Comment: if you want to use ObjectFactory use ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => ...);

Comment: yes .net mvc., what is the difference?  objectfactory is available somehow throughout hte application?  does it put things in a global cache like Httpcontext.application ?

Comment: ObjectFactory is a static gateway to an internal static Container object which is instantiated while using the **Initialize** method. Every call to ObjectFactory is channeled to this static container. if you configure and instantiate your own Container class, your are responsible for the accessibility and scope.